# boost regex smatch in recursive function behaves like a static variable

Tags: c++, regex, boost, static

I encountered a strange behavior using boost::regex.

The following function calls itself once (if invoked with argument 'true').

```
void regex_rek(bool recurse)
{
  boost::smatch match;
  if ( recurse )
  {
    std::string txt( "aaa" );
    boost::regex rgx("aaa");
    boost::regex_match(txt, match, rgx );
  }
  else
  {
    std::string txt("bbb");
    boost::regex rgx("bbb");
    boost::regex_match(txt, match, rgx );
  }

  std::cout <<"before: "<< std::string(match[0]) << std::endl;
  if (recurse)
  {
    regex_rek(false);
  }
  std::cout <<"after: "<< std::string(match[0]) << std::endl;

}
```

The output of this should be

```
before: aaa
before: bbb
after: bbb
after: aaa
```

but it is (for me, running on ubuntu-64bit, using boost-1.48):

```
before: aaa
before: bbb
after: bbb
after: bbb
```

on win64, msvc11, boost-1.53 i get something else:

```
before: aaa
before: bbb
after: bb
after: aa
```

No Joke. Is this my fault? Am I making a big mistake somewhere?

I figured out that if I use the `cmatch` version, everything is fine. but that's no choice for me, because my string may contain `0x0`.

Answer (score 2):

`smatch` does not contain a copy of the data matched on; instead it contains pointers into it. The data matched on is the variable `txt`, which goes out of scope immediately after you call `regex_match`. At this point, accessing `match` is undefined behavior and anything can happen.

Declare `txt` before `match`, and assign to it inside the if branches, and it should work correctly.

The `cmatch` version probably works because it contains pointers into a string literal, which never goes out of scope.